# Symfony 3.3 memcached

Tags: performance, symfony, caching, memcached, symfony-3.3

I've tried diffrent ways of using memcached. I did not find complete explanation, solution, good practice on how to use it with Symfony 3.3.

**Question 1: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-memcached-cache-adapter.**

Maybe I'm not seeing something here but how do I tell Symfony what I would like to cache(metadata, query, results - I am using doctrine)? Where I can find more configuration options? Is there something I can read about it?

**Question 2: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7rum/using-doctrine-memcached-caching-with-query-builder-in-symfony**

Running stats commands showed some items in memory but there's no performance increase. Nothing at all. I followed steps very carefully. Does any one know do I have to do something more to see the actual results?

I don't think it matters but as example I am using simple endpoint which is getting list of posts from database.

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1: how to use cache?

Please see this example from the blog you referred to ([New in Symfony 3.3: Memcached Cache Adapter](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-memcached-cache-adapter)):

```
$cacheProduct = $this->get('app.cache.products')->getItem($productId);
if (!$cacheProduct->isHit()) {
    $product = ...
    $cacheProduct->set($product);
    $this->get('app.cache.products')->save($cacheProduct);
} else {
    $product = $cacheProduct->get();
}
```

This cache adapter will allow *you* to store data in memory. This example uses memcache, but you can also use Redis for example. You have to decide which part of your code is too 'expensive' to perform at every request and can be cached. It's also up to you when the cache should be invalidated, which can be a real pain:

> There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.
>   https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096

The blog is about [Symfony's Cache Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html), but there is  [DoctrineCacheBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/usage.html) too. The difference between them can cause some confusion, because you can use Doctrine Cache without Doctrine ORM and vice versa.

If you want Doctrine to use `metadata_cache`, `result_cache` or `query_cache` take a look at [the configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers). Unfortunately I couldn't find any useful documentation about it's usage on Symfony.com.

## Question 2: no performance increase?

I think you're not using any caching mechanisms right now, so try to do so.

You can open a separate question with more details if you still encounter problems after you implemented caching mechanisms.

Comment: Stephan, thanks for quick response. I know how cache works. I've went through this example of memcached adapter in Symfony and I can't really get what I want. I want to store metadata and transformed dql but not results.And this here gets me only results(I might be wrong). I guess I will try to use DoctrineCacheBundle however it looks old and the description is not very accurate. It says it's for symfony2 but recent commits dropped support for old versions of Symfony. I will try it and let you know.